# Link duplicating

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I would like to create a list of links in this order

```
http://www.website.com/image_1.jpg
http://www.website.com/image_2.jpg
http://www.website.com/image_3.jpg
```

and so on until 15000.

How can I create a list of it ? tried dragging down the cell in excel but value didn't increase.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
="http://www.website.com/image_"&ROW()&".jpg"
```

and copy down to suit. Then select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the url without the `.jpg` in first cell (say A1 for example). Then in the cell next to it (B1) type:

```
=A1 & ".jpg"
```

Then select both cells and fill down. When finished, copy Column B and Paste> Values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having any trouble keeping the links active or wish to have a *'friendly'* name displayed instead of the entire link, put this into any cell.

```
=HYPERLINK("http://www.website.com/image_"&ROW(1:1)&".jpg", "image_"&ROW(1:1)&".jpg")
```

Fill down as necessary.